# Loading Indicator in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked and answered many times in this forum. But it does not work in what I am looking for.

I want to display a loading indicator while the ajax div is loading. There are cases when it takes a few minutes to load so it would be good to let the user know that the is loading.

From what I gathered it can be done in jquery. I am not too familiar with jquery yet. With this code the loading works but only for the first page.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('body').append('<div id="ajaxBusy"><p><img src="ajax-loader.gif"></p></div>'); 
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
});
```

My page is structured like this

---

Header Page

> -Div (display ajax here)
>
> > -Another div within the first loaded page(Load another page through ajax here)

---

I need it to display the loading indicator in the second div while it's loading. I am assuming that jquery "body" appends it to the main page body once and doesn't run again as it's within the same page. I did try to create a div and instead of body, load the div in jquery but it doesn't work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to add the loader gif to specific elements is to create a CSS class with the loader as a background instead of appending an actual image:

```
.ajax-loader {
    background: url(ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Then you just add that class to the element you are loading and remove it when it is done:

```
    // Removes any loaded images on Ajax success
   var removeLoader = function(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions)
    {
        $('.ajax-loader').removeClass('ajax-loader');
    };

    // Add the ajax loader to a specific element and remove it when successful
    $('.div1').addClass('ajax-loader').load('mypage.html', removeLoader);
```

Comment: This is certainly a interesting approach. What do you mean by ajaxOptions here? I am assuming by $('.div1') you mean $('#div1')

Comment: This might work but there is a slight problem with this. I am loading multiple pages within the div(depends what page the user selects). I need something a bit more dynamic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Loading the page through jquery might not be a good option unless as there will be lot of if else statements to figure out which page to load and it will get complicated. any suggestions?

Comment: Well my selector is just an example. Your $('#div1') would select the element with id div1. Now, if you load the page using Ajax or not depends on how you want your application to work like.

Answer (score 0):

considering that the div you want to load your image has an id="theDiv"

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#theDiv').append('<div id="ajaxBusy"><p><img src="ajax-loader.gif"></p></div>'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're appending your "ajaxBusy" div via Javascript? Why not just include the HTML on the page itself?

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="ajaxBusy">
    <p><img src="ajax-loader.gif"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try binding the ajaxStart and ajaxStop to the ajaxBusy div instead of the document.

```
$('#ajaxBusy').ajaxStart(function(){ 
  $(this).show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){ 
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I did think about it but in this case the image loads before the ajax page is requested. I only want to display the loading indicator when the website is waiting for a response not all the time. So I do need to append it.

Comment: You can set "ajaxBusy" to be hidden at first, and then simply show it/hide it again via Javascript when you want. 

<div id="ajaxBusy" class="hidden">

and set up a CSS class:
.hidden { display: none; }